# Hexagonal Card creation from what level up?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I am trying to build a base on which to create hexagonally shaped cards, there a few questions I've found here that have been helpful but I'm searching for my own answers, while more importantly learning latex/tex/tikz/pgf

I have this so far, and maybe someone can nudge me in the right direction:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


% 1:draw a hexagon
\newcommand{\hexagon}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \ang in {60,120,...,360}{
        \coordinate (\ang) at  (\ang:#1) ;}
        \draw (60) -- (120) -- (180) -- (240) -- (300) -- (360) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% 2:draw a hexagon from input radius
\newcommand{\hexagonTwo}[1]{
    \newdimen\R
    \R=#1
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        {[]
            \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {
                    -- (\x:\R)
                }-- cycle (90:\R);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzset{
    hexStyle/.style={color=black,
                     draw,
                     fill=blue!50,
                     line width=1,
                     inner xsep=2.5cm,
                     inner ysep=0.5cm
                    }
}

% 3:build a hexagon shape
\newcommand{\hexagonThree}{
        \node[name=hx, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, hexStyle] 
            {};
        \foreach \anchor/\placement in
        {corner 1/above, corner 2/above, corner 3/left, corner 4/left, corner 5/right, corner 6/right,
         side 1/above, side 2/left, side 3/left, side 4/right, side 5/right, side 6/right,
         center/above, text/left, mid/right, base/below, 307/above,
         west/above, east/above, north/below, south/above,
         north east/below, south east/above, north west/below, south west/above}
        \draw[shift=(hx.\anchor)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
            node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(hx.\anchor)}};
}

% 4:declare & build a hexagon from pgf
\pgfdeclareshape{rootHexagon}
{
    \savedmacro\sides{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sides{6}%
}
\savedmacro\anglestep{%
    \pgfmathdivide{360}{\sides}%
    \let\anglestep\pgfmathresult%
}
\savedmacro\calculateradii{%
    %
    % Get the node dimensions.
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \ifdim\pgf@y>\pgf@x%
        \pgf@x\pgf@y%
    \fi%
    %
    % Calculate i, the incircle radius 
    %
    \pgf@x1.41421\pgf@x%
    %
    % Calculate r, the polygon radius
    %
    % r = i / cos(360 / s / 2)
    %
    % (s = polygon sides)
    %
    \pgfmathdivide{180}{\sides}%
    \pgfmathsec@{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@x%
    %
    % Accommodate the minimum width/height.
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@ya>\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xa\pgf@ya%
    \fi%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@x.5\pgf@xa%
    \fi%
    \edef\radius{\the\pgf@x}%
    %
    % Now calculate the anchor radius from the outer sep.
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@ya>\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xa\pgf@ya%
    \fi
    %
    % Take into account the miter length.
    %
    % m = o / sin (90 - (360 / s / 2))
    %
    % (o = outer sep, s = sides)
    %
    \pgfmathdivide{180}{\sides}%
    \pgfmathsubtract@{90}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathcosec@{\pgfmathresult}%
    \advance\pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa%
    \edef\anchorradius{\the\pgf@x}%
    %
    % Save both radii.
    %
    \addtosavedmacro{\radius}%
    \addtosavedmacro{\anchorradius}%
}
\savedmacro\startangle{%
    \pgfmathdivide{360}{\sides}%
    \let\anglestep\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sides{\sides}%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\anglestep}{2}%
    \pgfmathsubtract@{90}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathadd{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shape border rotate}}%
    \let\startangle\pgfmathresult%
}
%
% Saved anchors.
%
\savedanchor{\centerpoint}{%
    \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
}%
\savedanchor{\midpoint}{%
    \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{+.5ex}%
}%  
%
% Other anchors.
%
\anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
\anchor{mid}{\midpoint}%
\anchor{base}{\centerpoint\pgf@y=0pt}%
\anchor{north}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\anchorradius}}}%
\anchor{south}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\anchorradius}}}%
\anchor{east}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{0pt}}}%
\anchor{west}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{0pt}}}%
\anchor{north east}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{\anchorradius}}}%
\anchor{north west}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{\anchorradius}}}%
\anchor{south east}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{-\anchorradius}}}%
\anchor{south west}{%
    \calculateradii%
    \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{-\anchorradius}}}%   
%
% Background path.
%
\backgroundpath{%
    \calculateradii%
    \pgfpathmoveto{%
        \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\startangle}{\radius}}%
    }%
    \let\angle\startangle%
    \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter=\sides\relax% 
            \pgfpathclose%
        \else%
            \pgfmathadd@{\angle}{\anglestep}%
            \let\angle\pgfmathresult%
            \pgfpathlineto{%
                \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\angle}{\radius}}%
            }%
    \repeatpgfmathloop% 
}%
\anchorborder{%
    %
    % Save x and y.
    %
    \edef\externalx{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef\externaly{\the\pgf@y}%
    %
    % Adjust the location of the external 
    % point relative to \centerpoint.
    %
    \centerpoint%
    \pgf@xa\externalx\relax%
    \pgf@ya\externaly\relax%
    \advance\pgf@xa\pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@ya\pgf@y%
    \edef\externalx{\the\pgf@xa}%
    \edef\externaly{\the\pgf@ya}%
    %
    % Get the angle of the external point to the \centerpoint.
    %
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\externalx}{\externaly}}%
    %
    % Locate the appropriate sides on the polygon border...
    %
    \pgfmathsubtract@{\pgfmathresult}{\startangle}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0pt\relax%
        \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{360}%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
    \pgfmathfloor@{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
    \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{\startangle}%
    \let\firstangle\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
    \let\secondangle\pgfmathresult%
    \calculateradii%
    %
    % ...and thus, the point on the polygon border.
    %
    \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{+\externalx}{+\externaly}}%
        {%
            \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
                {\pgfqpointpolar{+\firstangle}{+\anchorradius}}%
            }%  
            {%
                \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
                    {\pgfqpointpolar{+\secondangle}{+\anchorradius}}%
            }%  
}
%
% More hackery for when the rootHex is positioned using 
% a `corner <n+1>' or `side <n+1>' anchor, where n is the maximum 
% number of sides of any previously drawn rootHex.
%
\expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\csname pgf@sh@s@rootHex\endcsname{%
    \c@pgf@counta\sides\relax%
    \pgfmathloop%
        \ifnum\c@pgf@counta>0\relax%
            \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@rootHex@corner\space\the\c@pgf@counta}{%
            %
            % ...(manually \xdef as \gdef is normally used by \anchor)...
            %
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@corner\space\the\c@pgf@counta\endcsname{%
                \noexpand\calculateradii%
                \noexpand\pgfmathsubtract@{\the\c@pgf@counta}{1}%
                \noexpand\pgfmathmultiply@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\startangle}%
                \noexpand\let\noexpand\angle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                \noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                    {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\angle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}%
            }%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@side\space\the\c@pgf@counta\endcsname{%
                \noexpand\calculateradii%
                \noexpand\pgfmathsubtract@{\the\c@pgf@counta}{1}%
                \noexpand\pgfmathmultiply@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\startangle}%
                \noexpand\let\noexpand\firstangle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                \noexpand\let\noexpand\secondangle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                \noexpand\pgfpointlineattime{0.5}%
                    {\noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                        {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\firstangle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}}%
                    {\noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                        {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\secondangle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}}%
            }%
        }{\c@pgf@counta0\relax}% 
        \advance\c@pgf@counta-1\relax%
    \repeatpgfmathloop% 
}%
}
```

1 & 2 are exercises in 'not much' and 3 is a start, the commented 4th I'm not at a point to actually do but think I should be moving toward. I need to build a hexagon card, and then get control over every point inside for node placement, etc.(i.e. import art, add text or other shapes, etc. but first things first). I need to control size, etc, which I cant seem to. My first step is building the actual thing, with actual measurements of sides and inside.

I'm mostly trying to establish first principles for something not 100% clear to me, any input appreciated.

EDIT:

After some effort, the 4th is taking shape, as a modified implementation of the regular polygon from the shapes library.

Comment: The arguments for \hexagonOne and \hexagonTwo are the corner radius values.

Any page you create will be a rectangle, even using \documentclass{standalone}.  Even if you create a formal tikz hexagon shape complete with anchor points, the text area will still be a rectangle.  \parshape and shapepar can create hexagon shaped text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally wouldn't post a solution using [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) when you've specifically tagged your question with `tikz`.  However, I see that you are not getting many responses to your questions.  Note that `asymptote` code can be embedded within Latex or can be compiled into PDF files independent of Latex.

If I were designing hexagonal cards, I would do something like the following code.  The `pair anchor(...)` function returns an anchor point with the hexagon as you requested in [your other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297778/grid-of-anchors-within-a-hexagon).

I've also demonstrated how to import graphics and use clipping.

```
unitsize(1inch);
real height = 1.5;
real halfDiagonal = height / 2 / Cos(30);
path border = scale(halfDiagonal)*
    (dir(0)--dir(60)--dir(120)--dir(180)--dir(240)--dir(300)--cycle);

pair anchor(real degrees, real fractionFromCenter)
{
    path ray = rotate(degrees)*((0,0)--(2*height,0));
    return scale(fractionFromCenter)*intersectionpoint(ray,border);
}

fill(border, gray);
label(graphic("logs.eps","height=0.35in"), anchor(90,0.5));
layer();
label(graphic("lemons.eps","height=0.5in"), anchor(270,0.5));
layer();

dot(anchor(  0,0.0), black);
dot(anchor(  0,0.5), red);
dot(anchor( 30,0.5), blue);
dot(anchor(150,0.9), orange);

label(rotate(90)*"Hello", anchor(180,0.5), white);
filldraw(shift(anchor(330,0.9))*scale(0.2)*unitcircle, yellow, 3+red);
clip(border);
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting too. I've been using tikz/pgf, having centered on it as a first step trying to learn, but I may look deeper into asymptote because of your answer, thanks.