# grid of anchors within a hexagon

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, shapes, tikz-shape

So I have a base shape I am beginning to work with, which is just a regular polygon shape from shapes.geometric. How do I create a grid of anchors within this shape? I know that it is just math + pgf I need to work through, and a simple thing eventually, unless I am wrong about how I need to go about movement and placement with a shape I've created. Its mostly about setting up my limited understanding of math through an understanding of pgf, any input appreciated.

```
\pgfdeclareshape{rootHex}{
    \savedmacro\sides{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sides{6}%
    }
    \savedmacro\anglestep{%
        \pgfmathdivide{360}{\sides}%
        \let\anglestep\pgfmathresult%
    }
    \savedmacro\calculateradii{%
        %
        % Get the node dimensions.
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \advance\pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \ifdim\pgf@y>\pgf@x%
            \pgf@x\pgf@y%
        \fi%
        %
        % Calculate i, the incircle radius 
        %
        \pgf@x1.41421\pgf@x%
        %
        % Calculate r, the polygon radius
        %
        % r = i / cos(360 / s / 2)
        %
        % (s = polygon sides)
        %
        \pgfmathdivide{180}{\sides}%
        \pgfmathsec@{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@x%
        %
        % Accommodate the minimum width/height.
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@ya>\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@xa\pgf@ya%
        \fi%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@x.5\pgf@xa%
        \fi%
        \edef\radius{\the\pgf@x}%
        %
        % Now calculate the anchor radius from the outer sep.
        %
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@ya>\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@xa\pgf@ya%
        \fi
        %
        % Take into account the miter length.
        %
        % m = o / sin (90 - (360 / s / 2))
        %
        % (o = outer sep, s = sides)
        %
        \pgfmathdivide{180}{\sides}%
        \pgfmathsubtract@{90}{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathcosec@{\pgfmathresult}%
        \advance\pgf@x\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa%
        \edef\anchorradius{\the\pgf@x}%
        %
        % Save both radii.
        %
        \addtosavedmacro{\radius}%
        \addtosavedmacro{\anchorradius}%
    }
    \savedmacro\startangle{%
        \pgfmathdivide{360}{\sides}%
        \let\anglestep\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sides{\sides}%
        \pgfmathdivide@{\anglestep}{2}%
        \pgfmathsubtract@{90}{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathadd{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shape border rotate}}%
        \let\startangle\pgfmathresult%
    }
    %
    % Saved anchors.
    %
    \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }%
    \savedanchor{\midpoint}{%
        \pgf@x.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{+.5ex}%
    }%  
    %
    % Other anchors.
    %
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}%
    \anchor{mid}{\midpoint}%
    \anchor{base}{\centerpoint\pgf@y=0pt}%
    \anchor{north}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\anchorradius}}}%
    \anchor{south}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\anchorradius}}}%
    \anchor{east}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{0pt}}}%
    \anchor{west}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{0pt}}}%
    \anchor{north east}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{\anchorradius}}}%
    \anchor{north west}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{\anchorradius}}}%
    \anchor{south east}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{\anchorradius}{-\anchorradius}}}%
    \anchor{south west}{%
        \calculateradii%
        \csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@border\endcsname{\pgfqpoint{-\anchorradius}{-\anchorradius}}}%   
    %
    % Background path.
    %
    \backgroundpath{%
        \calculateradii%
        \pgfpathmoveto{%
            \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\startangle}{\radius}}%
        }%
        \let\angle\startangle%
        \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\pgfmathcounter=\sides\relax% 
                \pgfpathclose%
            \else%
                \pgfmathadd@{\angle}{\anglestep}%
                \let\angle\pgfmathresult%
                \pgfpathlineto{%
                    \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpointpolar{\angle}{\radius}}%
                }%
        \repeatpgfmathloop% 
    }%
    \anchorborder{%
        %
        % Save x and y.
        %
        \edef\externalx{\the\pgf@x}%
        \edef\externaly{\the\pgf@y}%
        %
        % Adjust the location of the external 
        % point relative to \centerpoint.
        %
        \centerpoint%
        \pgf@xa\externalx\relax%
        \pgf@ya\externaly\relax%
        \advance\pgf@xa\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@ya\pgf@y%
        \edef\externalx{\the\pgf@xa}%
        \edef\externaly{\the\pgf@ya}%
        %
        % Get the angle of the external point to the \centerpoint.
        %
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\externalx}{\externaly}}%
        %
        % Locate the appropriate sides on the polygon border...
        %
        \pgfmathsubtract@{\pgfmathresult}{\startangle}%
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{360}%
        \fi%
        \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
        \pgfmathfloor@{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
        \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{\startangle}%
        \let\firstangle\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{\anglestep}%
        \let\secondangle\pgfmathresult%
        \calculateradii%
        %
        % ...and thus, the point on the polygon border.
        %
        \pgfpointintersectionoflines{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{+\externalx}{+\externaly}}%
            {%
                \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
                    {\pgfqpointpolar{+\firstangle}{+\anchorradius}}%
                }%  
                {%
                    \pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}%
                        {\pgfqpointpolar{+\secondangle}{+\anchorradius}}%
                }%  
    }
    %
    % More hackery for when the rootHex is positioned using 
    % a `corner <n+1>' or `side <n+1>' anchor, where n is the maximum 
    % number of sides of any previously drawn rootHex.
    %
    \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\csname pgf@sh@s@rootHex\endcsname{%
        \c@pgf@counta\sides\relax%
        \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\c@pgf@counta>0\relax%
                \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@rootHex@corner\space\the\c@pgf@counta}{%
                %
                % ...(manually \xdef as \gdef is normally used by \anchor)...
                %
                \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@corner\space\the\c@pgf@counta\endcsname{%
                    \noexpand\calculateradii%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathsubtract@{\the\c@pgf@counta}{1}%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathmultiply@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\startangle}%
                    \noexpand\let\noexpand\angle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                    \noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                        {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\angle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}%
                }%
                \expandafter\xdef\csname pgf@anchor@rootHex@side\space\the\c@pgf@counta\endcsname{%
                    \noexpand\calculateradii%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathsubtract@{\the\c@pgf@counta}{1}%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathmultiply@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\startangle}%
                    \noexpand\let\noexpand\firstangle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                    \noexpand\pgfmathadd@{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}{\noexpand\anglestep}%
                    \noexpand\let\noexpand\secondangle\noexpand\pgfmathresult%
                    \noexpand\pgfpointlineattime{0.5}%
                        {\noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                            {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\firstangle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}}%
                        {\noexpand\pgfpointadd{\noexpand\centerpoint}%
                            {\noexpand\pgfqpointpolar{\noexpand\secondangle}{\noexpand\anchorradius}}}%
                }%
            }{\c@pgf@counta0\relax}% 
            \advance\c@pgf@counta-1\relax%
        \repeatpgfmathloop% 
    }%
}
```

EDIT:

for clarity, I want to specify (regular, not saved) anchors along the edges and within the space of the shape, not just the edges. I'm guessing I need to travel along some polar coordinate thing I create and add anchors where I want, but 2d cartesian x,y would suffice for for my current (perhaps imagined) needs. 
[image]

Comment: what exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at page 600, all regular polygon shapes already have `a.corner i` and `a.side i` anchors (`a` is node's name, and `i` is a number between 1 and `regular polygon sides`) which point to every polygon corner o midpoints in segments. What else do you need?

Comment: For clarity, see image. I want to create referencable anchors along all edge & corners, as well as a number of interior points within the shape.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use all these anchors for node placement and only like a coordinate system. You don't need anchors defined in `\pgfdeclareshape`, a `perpendicular` coordinate system with `corner` and `side` anchors could be enough.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    hex/.style={regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=10mm,
      inner sep=0mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      rotate=0,
        draw
    }
]
\node[hex] (A) {};
\node[hex, above right=.5cm of A] (B) {};
\foreach \j in {A,B}{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}{
        \fill[red] (\j.corner \i) circle(1pt);
        \fill[red] (\j.side \i) circle(1pt);
    }
    \foreach \i in {corner 2, side 1, corner 1}
        \fill[red] (\j.side 2-|\j.\i) circle(1pt);
    \foreach \i in {side 2, corner 2, side 1, corner 1, side 6}
        \fill[red] (\j.corner 3-|\j.\i) circle(1pt);
    \foreach \i in {corner 2, side 1, corner 1}
        \fill[red] (\j.side 3-|\j.\i) circle(1pt);
    }
\draw (A.corner 3-|A.corner 2) to[out=10,in=120] (B.side 3-|B.corner 5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The anchors will be for node placement within a shape, not references between shapes. Interesting to see, and yes I am still working through a lot of just basic placement issues.

Comment: what does the "-|" mean exactly

Comment: @blueblank These `non anchors` can be used for node placement within a shape. `A-|B` means intersection point between horizontal line from A and vertical line from B. Without specific `anchor`, `A` means `A.center`. You can use `-|` or `|-` which means intersection between vertical and horizontal.